# BCP command using xp_cmdshell uses what kind of protocol?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ftp, sql-server-2008-r2, sftp

I'm using a BCP command in sql server to import data from a flat file to a table in my database. The server it's retrieving from uses FTP and SFTP protocol. I have asked the security admin to give the sql server account access to that server to read the specific location where the file is. When I run the BCP command using xp_cmdshell, what protocol will it use?

Comment: I think your security guy needs to be more concerned with allowing `xp_cmdshell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BCP connects to the file using ODBC. Probably a good idea to first copy the file to the server and read from there instead of reading across the network.

Comment: ODBC as opposed to the native client? Sounds like an interesting choice for a tool that only has to worry about one platform and whose purpose is speed.  I'm not saying you're wrong, but do you have documentation for that?

Comment: SQLNCLIxx.dll is just a wrapper for ODBC and OLEDB to make it simpler for deployment, management and programming (both APIs in a single DLL). It's called SQL Native to differentiate from MDAC which is shipped by Windows and targets all kinds of data stores. SQLNCLI only targets SQL Server and ships with SQL Server, independent of Windows.

Comment: Again... do you have documentation for that?

Comment: Very little detailed documentation remains on BCP as it hasn't been updated since 2005 (fixes not withstanding). 2000/2005 BOL still have it  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa196743(v=SQL.80).aspx but later versions have removed most details. See note near the bottom of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx indicating it's written using ODBC bulk-copy and look in the ODBC box in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/connectivity.aspx. Still don't believe it, run an ODBC or wireshark trace and you'll see the ODBC calls.

Comment: @SQLmojoe would it be correct to say the protocol SQL Server uses is TDS (Tabular Data Stream) which envelopes ODBC?

Comment: Kinda the other way around. TDS is an app level protocol designed for SQL Server. ODBC is an API that encapsulates functions relevant to the intended data store. Most commonly used for databases (SQL Server, Oracle-TNS, etc...) but can work with pretty much any data store such as flat files or excel files. Your SQL Server app talks to ODBC which converts them to TDS and encapsulates into the packets for the net-library used which can then be sent. It can also do other things like emulating functionality or data type conversions.